# How can I get data from JSON File?

Tags: python, json

In python language. How can I get the inside data individually? For example, I want to get "Critical" for "table one for me" data.

Sorry for my bad English.

JSON File

```
{
    "domain" : [{
        "table one for me":
            [
                ["Test1", "Critical"],
                ["Test2", "High"],
                ["Test3","Medium"]
            ]
    },{
        "table two for you":
            [
                ["Test1", "Critical"],
                ["Test2", "High"],
                ["Test3","Medium"],
                ["Test4", "Low"]
            ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: You can use [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to parse the file into python objects. If you don't know how to reference the python objects, then you really need a basic tutorial. Write some code, give it a try, and if you still have problems, post that code with your example.

Comment: Ok. How do you import the json data into python. Do you know how to do that? Next, how do you interact with dictionaries? Combine these steps and you'll get your answer...

Comment: Also, there are two `Test1 -> Critical` instances in your json. Which one are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are like this: `{'key':'value'}` and and you can access *value* using `your_dict.get('key')` or `your_dict['key']`.

Lists have this structure `['first element', 'second', 'third']` and you access the elements using integers e.g. `your_list[0]` for the first element. So you can do:

```
j = {
    "domain" : [{
        "table one for me":
            [
                ["Test1", "Critical"],
                ["Test2", "High"],
                ["Test3","Medium"]
            ]
    },{
        "table two for you":
            [
                ["Test1", "Critical"],
                ["Test2", "High"],
                ["Test3","Medium"],
                ["Test4", "Low"]
            ]
    }]
}
```

```
>>> j['domain'][0]['table one for me'][0]
['Test1', 'Critical']
```

```
>>> j.get('domain')[0].get('table one for me')[0]
['Test1', 'Critical']
```